# Add GridViewDropDown Column telerik gridView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, telerik

Is there a way to add GridDropDownColumn in asp.NET . I have a telerik GRIDVIEW and i want to add a DropdownColumn in GridView . I am trying to do something like this but DataSource there is not a valid property .
Is there any way like this too add GridDropDownColumn from codebehind in asp.net

```
  ((GridDropDownColumn)this.radGridView2.Columns[2]).DataSource = new String[] { "Block", "Active" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

If you have generated drop down column  using template field then on row bound event you can bind every drop down there.

Follow below steps.

1) generate Row Bound Event of rad grid

2) find template column and the control

3) Bind data source

Just complete step one by one and ALL SET